# sql exclude rows based on first occurrence of data and conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have created a dataset that has columns for 2 customers:

```
Cust_No Transaction_date    amount  credit_debit    running_total   row_num
1       5/27/2022           800     D               -200            1
1       5/26/2022           300     D               600             2
1       5/22/2022           800     C               900             3
1       5/20/2022           100     C               100             4
                    
9       5/16/2022           500     D               -300            1
9       5/14/2022           300     D               200             2
9       5/6/2022            200     C               500             3 
9       5/5/2022            500     D               300             4
9       5/2/2022            300     D               800             5
9       5/2/2022            500     C               1100            6
9       5/1/2022            500     C               600             7
9       5/1/2022            100     C               100             8
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
Cust_No Transaction_date    amount  credit_debit    running_total   row_num
1       5/27/2022           800     D               -200            1
1       5/26/2022           300     D               600             2
1       5/22/2022           800     C               900             3

                    
9       5/16/2022           500     D               -300            1
9       5/14/2022           300     D               200             2
9       5/6/2022            200     C               500             3 
9       5/5/2022            500     D               300             4
9       5/2/2022            300     D               800             5
9       5/2/2022            500     C               1100            6
```

I sorted the dataset based on latest transaction for each customer.

We note the latest transaction amount and search for first occurrence of same amount that was a credit (C) and exclude the rest of the rows after it.
In the example above: Customer 9 has lastest debit transaction of 500, so we look for most recent credit transaction of 500 and exclude all the rows after that for customer 9.

Progress Made so far:

1. calculated the running total using logic:

```
sum (case when credit_debit ='C' then amount else -1*amount end) over (partition by cust_no order by transaction_date desc ) as running_total
```

I also got the data using lead 1,2,3,4,5 but this is not efficient and I could have multiple rows before I find the first credit number with amount same as 1st row:

```
case when lead(amount, 1) over(partition by cust_no order by transaction_date desc) = amount then amount else null end as lead1
```

Comment: use of `row_number() over(partition by cust_no order by transaction_date asc)` would identify the first row, then as a cte or derived table exclude the rows where that result is 1

Comment: So the date in `transaction_date` is really in that format (`M/D/YYYY`) or is this just a copy paste mistake?

Comment: @ paul : There could be different number of rows that might need to be excluded for different customers. excluding the first row after using row_number( ) over ( partition by....... ASC) will delete just 1 record.

Comment: @FanoFN : It's m/d/yyyy

Comment: Wait, is this MySQL or postgresql?

Comment: Anyway, I'm assuming that the `transaction_date` datatype is not `DATE`, maybe it's `VARCHAR()`? The standard date format in both MySQL and postgresql is `YYYY-MM-DD`.  If that's the case here, the `order by transaction_date desc` here won't work as intended. [See this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ae3a3b24eab2c0fe6bdc0c97ee5f25d) for reference. Notice the `Cust_no=9` order for `transaction_date` is not correct?

Comment: *We note the latest transaction amount and search for first occurrence of same amount that was a credit (C)* What if the most last transaction is `C`?

Comment: @Akina : we would always have the first record as D (debit)

Answer (score 0):

No sure which dbms this is for but it need a lateral join in postgres.

It searches for the most recent transaction identified when rn = 1, then it matches that amount to an earlier credit transaction of the same amount and using the rn of that row to form a boundary of row numbers to be returned:

```
with CTE as (
    select
          Cust_No, Transaction_date, amount, credit_debit, running_total
        , row_number() over(partition by cust_no order by transaction_date DESC) as rn
    from mytable
    )
, RANGE as (
    select *
    from CTE
    left join lateral (
        select c.rn as ignore_after
        from CTE as c
        where CTE.Cust_No = c.Cust_No
            and CTE.amount = c.amount 
            and  c.credit_debit = 'C'
            and CTE.rn = 1
        order by c.rn ASC
        limit 1
        ) oa on true
    where CTE.rn = 1
    )
select 
     CTE.*
from CTE
inner join RANGE on CTE.rn between RANGE.rn and RANGE.ignore_after
                and CTE.cust_no = RANGE.cust_no
```

> ```
> Cust_No | Transaction_date | amount | credit_debit | running_total | rn
> ------: | :--------------- | -----: | :----------- | ------------: | -:
>       1 | 2022-05-27       |    800 | D            |          -200 |  1
>       1 | 2022-05-26       |    300 | D            |           600 |  2
>       1 | 2022-05-22       |    800 | C            |           900 |  3
>       9 | 2022-05-16       |    500 | D            |          -300 |  1
>       9 | 2022-05-14       |    300 | D            |           200 |  2
>       9 | 2022-05-06       |    200 | C            |           500 |  3
>       9 | 2022-05-05       |    500 | D            |           300 |  4
>       9 | 2022-05-02       |    300 | D            |           800 |  5
>       9 | 2022-05-02       |    500 | C            |          1100 |  6
> ```

for postgres see: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1a00a59a4d5902f301592eeb3e55d66f)*

nb: for an "outer apply" example I have also used SQL Server in the following fiddle  see: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22c8e367f678b9d61278bcb74d992e26)*